# SQL statement in VBA Excel

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have a problem with a SQL Statement in VBA Excel. I can't use ORDER BY together with GROUP BY and I don't understand why.
If I delete ORDER BY I don't get errors.
Can anyone help me figure out where am I wrong?

Thanks a lot to everyone!!

Here is my code:

```
Dim RS As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim sConn As String
Dim stmSQL As String

sConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & ActiveWorkbook.Path & "/OrigineDati.xlsx" & ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES'"

stmSQL = "SELECT COL5 FROM [DATABASE$] WHERE COL9 = 'PITTSBURGH' AND LEFT(COL5,2) = 'BA'" _
& "GROUP BY COL5" _
& "ORDER BY COL5 ASC"

Foglio1.Range("A2").CurrentRegion.ClearContents

RS.Open stmSQL, sConn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

Foglio1.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset RS

RS.Close
Set RS = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

missing space ? try with

```
& " ORDER BY COL5 ASC"  'space before ORDER
```